# Swift Properties

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So, while learning swift, I've run into an issue with adding values to an array property. When I try to print the first value of the array after adding a value to it, I receive an index out of bounds error. How do I add a value to an array property that is accessible to the entire class?

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var geofences = [Geofence]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getFences()
        print(self.geofences[0])
    }

    func getFences() {
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Geofence")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: "Peter")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (fences: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && fences != nil {
                if let fences = fences {
                    for (index, element) in fences.enumerate() {
                        var unique_id = element.objectId
                        var fence_radius = element["radius"] as! Int
                        var fence_name = element["name"] as! String
                        var lat = element["centerPoint"].latitude
                        var lon = element["centerPoint"].longitude
                        var center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                        var new_fence: Geofence? = Geofence(uniqueID: unique_id!, radius: fence_radius, centerPoint: center, name: fence_name)
                        self.geofences.append(new_fence!)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: It seems I oversimplified the issue. Here is the code that's getting the index out of bounds error. When I retrieve the geofence from Parse, the geofences array is populated, but once it exits the getFences method, the array is emptied.

Comment: I don't get index out of bounds error with that code.

Comment: Are you sure the index out of bounds error is in the code you posted?

Comment: I had posted code I thought was similar to my issue, but it seems it was over simplified. I've posted the exact code I'm working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your print call is being run before `getFences()` has had time to populate the array. You can check this with another print call outside of `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: Okay, I put the same print statement at the end of the getFences method and outside query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock and the same error occurs. After placing a breakpoint at the end of the getFences method and inspecting self.geofences, the array is emptied I have no idea why!

Comment: As a helpful thought experiment, imagine that it takes 30 seconds before the findObjects block executes. Sp anything that happens in that **block**, like populating the geofences array, won't happen until 30 seconds after your view loads. The viewDidLoad function would execute, and the getFences function would execute, but not the block. What would you expect geofences to contain during that time? [An empty array] Are you trying to access it when its not ready yet? [Yes]

Comment: It's possible that a print call at the end of the method is still being run prior to the enumeration code in findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. Doing a print(NSDate()) to accompany each attempt might let you know. In any case, you can probably create a new method to do things with that data that you call at the end of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock.

Comment: You're right, I used 
    while (self.geofences.isEmpty) {
            print("still empty")
        }
After it left the while loop, it worked